# JavaScript: Executing chained methods in any order

Tags: javascript

**Suppose** I have a function called `log` which simply prints the given string.

Can I refactor my code so both of these function could work?

```
log("needsChange").doSomethingWithTheStringBeforePrintingIt();
log("perfectStringToPrint");
```

Comment: That syntax is possible if log returns the function doSomething, or an object with that method.

Comment: @Shilly Yes but the problem is that the string has already been printed out so it's to late to do anything on it.

Comment: You obv have to do all the edits before printing the string. Emil's answer shown you a possibility how this can be done. If you have a way to detect if a string is 'perfectStringToPrint', it's still possible to get this exact syntax by moving the actual console.log call into 'doSomethingWithTheStringBeforePrintingIt' if 'needsChange' is detected as not being perfect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made a library to solve this issue
https://github.com/omidh28/clarifyjs

Answer (score 2):

You can do something similar with nested class logics:

```js
var log = (function() {
  //Class
  var _log = (function() {
    function _log(message) {
      this.message = message;
    }
    _log.prototype.doSomethingWithTheStringBeforePrintingIt = function() {
      this.message = this.message.split("").reverse().join("");
      return this;
    };
    _log.prototype.capitalizeFirstWord = function() {
      this.message = this.message[0].toUpperCase() + this.message.substr(1);
      return this;
    };
    _log.prototype.print = function() {
      return this.message;
    };
    return _log;
  }());
  //Instancer function
  return function log(message) {
    //Return instance of class
    return new _log(message);
  };
})();
//Test
console.log(log("needsChange")
  .doSomethingWithTheStringBeforePrintingIt()
  .capitalizeFirstWord()
  .print(), log("perfectStringToPrint")
  .print());
```

If you are comfortable with promises, then you can do something like this:

```js
var logger = (function() {
  //Class
  var _log = (function() {
    function _log(message) {
      var _this = this;
      this.message = message;
      this.promise = null;
      this.promises = [];
      this.promise = Promise.all(this.promises).then(function(values) {
        console.log(_this.message); // [3, 1337, "foo"] 
      });
    }
    _log.prototype.reverse = function() {
      var self = this;
      this.promises.push(new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        setTimeout(resolve, 0, (function() {
          self.message = self.message.split("").reverse().join("");
        })());
      }));
      return this;
    };
    _log.prototype.capitalizeFirst = function() {
      var self = this;
      this.promises.push(new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        setTimeout(resolve, 0, (function() {
          self.message = self.message[0].toUpperCase() + self.message.substr(1);
        })());
      }));
      return this;
    };
    return _log;
  }());
  //Instancer function
  return function log(message) {
    //Return instance of class
    return new _log(message);
  };
})();
//Test
logger("needsChange").reverse().capitalizeFirst().reverse(); //Capitalizes last letter
logger("perfectStringToPrint");
```

This removes the need for a `.print` call.